# Terminal Ping, how to get simple integer

Tags: terminal, ping

i am wondering how exactly you would get a simple integer result instead of all the miscellaneous information such as the packet size, transmission number and target.

To elaborate: 
I would prefer the output to look like:

`117.85`

A single integer response, similar to how the syntax: `ping -c 1 google.com` returns a single result, however i would prefer the method to omit the detailed ping report and only displays a single number.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
ping -c 1 google.com | grep "time=" | sed -E "s/(.*)time=([.0-9]+) ms/\2/"
```

If you want to get an minimal value for some number of requests use:

```
ping -q -c 5 google.com | tail -1 | cut -d "=" -f 2 | cut -d "/" -f 1
```

Replace `1` in `-f 1` with:

- `2` for average
- `3` for maximum

Comment: Brilliant, this worked perfectly

Comment: Or `ping -c 1 google.com | sed -nE "/time=/s/(.*)time=([.0-9]+) ms/\2/p"` if you want to keep it short :-)